# How to divide each pixel calculation of Mandelbrot into different nodes?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, mandelbrot

[image]

My question here is what data structure should I use to distribute the work to each threads and get the calculated value from them. First thing in my mind is fill vector[0] .. vector[63999] (for 800x800 pixel) with struct that holds x,y and iterate_value. Pass those vector to each node -> then further divide the given vector to each core(Os-thread) -> then further divide the given vector to each thread. Is there any other possible way to send and received the values? and also if I do it in vector way should I pass the vector by pass by value or pass by reference, which one would be better in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different points of the mandelbrot set take varying amounts of time to compute (points near the edge are more expensive), so giving each worker an even number of pixels will have some of them finishing faster than others.

Break the image into small rectangles (tiles). Create a work list using a multithreaded queue, and fill it with the tiles. Each worker thread loops, picking a tile off the work list and submitting the results, until the work list is empty.

Comment: thank you rmmh for the answer .. The place I am confused is the breaking the image part. So lets say I divide the image into 2 - this is simple just into two but while dividing by 3 does it matter how I divide the image (cause it will never be homogeneously divided and in latter case say while dividing into 5000 threads ( 800/500 = 1.6) decimal gets lost and some pixel are not included into the tiles)

Comment: @goonda, just pick a tile size and figure out the number needed to cover the image. The tiles don't need to all be the same size either. With a work queue like rmmh suggests, the number of work units (tiles) doesn't need to match the number of workers.

Comment: ok Last question - while collecting calculated values from the all the threads in the each core(say each core used 13 threads) shall I collect those values in vector  ( like vector[0] ... vector[12])? and return it for further use ?

Answer (score 2):

Pixels are evenly spaced, so why send the coordinates for each one? Just tell each node the x and y coordinates of its lower left pixel, the spacing between pixels, and the number of pixels. This way, your work unit specification is a small constant size.

As far as the larger design goes, there is no point in having more worker threads than physical cores to run on. The context switches of multiple threads per core only reduces performance.

Comment: appreciate your answer man. can you give me idea on how  shall I divide the 2d image into 2,3, 13, ... . I have commented in rmmh answer about how to divide the image. I am still confused in this dividing the image part. And yes I will be using many threads